# What is the easiest way to implement dark mode on a html document?

Tags: react-native, android-webview

For example, if I have a link like https://cultivate-newsletter-html.s3.amazonaws.com/html-mtrgr0fqddar2d1movb1qeutr0sne3mg29uuvk81 , how can I turn this to have a dark mode experience?

Currently I am rendering this in an web view on react native, and I also do have access to the actual html document.

One way I could think of would be to directly modify the css on the html document...but I am not confident that I can grab all the elements that should change to white texts on all types of html document.